# How to create ActiveX DLL in Visual C++

Tags: c++, dll, activex

Is there a tutorial/reference for creating an ActiveX DLL in Visual Studio 2008 C++ ?

I've got a DLL built with the DLLRegisterServer/UnregisterServer, and it's registered, but I'm having a little trouble figuring out what name to use to reference it (from a vbscript) and how to make sure my functions are exported correctly. Do I have to put my functions in a special class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are a *lot* of details to get right.  Best thing to do is to use ATL and the built-in [ATL object wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s7ak6e7.aspx).  It auto-generates a bunch of files so that the IDL, type library, registration script, class wrapper and event proxies are all done correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The component's ProgID is normally defined in the project's .rgs file.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to nobugz

> how to make sure my functions are exported correctly

Visual Studio contains OleView.exe. You can open your dll from it and see the list of props and methods.

As for tutorial, check here: [ATL Concepts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ax346b7%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)